# Bash configuration on Mac OS X 10.4+

Tags: macos, bash, configuration, shell

When configuring the bash on OSX via `~/.profile` it seems to completely ignore it as soon as `~/.bash_profile` exists. If this is correct and expected behavior, should I add my extra configuration stuff to `~/.bash_profile` as well or use it instead of `~/.profile`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's expected behaviour. See [here](http://telin.ugent.be/~slippens/drupal/bashrc_and_others)

> When bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option, it
>   first reads and executes commands from
>   the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists. After reading that file, it
>   looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands
>   from the first one that exists and is
>   readable.

So only the first readable one counts.

As for which you should use, it's up to you - unless there are corporate policies or something else that creates a specific one, or relies on a specific one existing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be "source ~/.profile"